# Sonata Admin - two dependent list in one tab

Tags: sonata-admin

Is it possible to create a tab with two dependent lists in the Sonata Admin Bundle?
I have an entity with categories and an entity with subcategories (many-to-many).
I would like to create a tab where I could select a group and assign subgroups to it (or add missing subgroups).
When selecting another group, the list of subgroups should be refreshed.